# Finding the inverse of a degree-$5$ polynomial using its graph

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

As far as I know, real polynomials of degree $\geq 5$ are known to be non-solvable. This implies that there are, in general, major algebraic difficulties in finding their roots and, provided they admit an inverse in some subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, one cannot find this inverse.

However, it is easy to use some computer software and plot a polynomial like this in the real plane. Provided we know regions in which this polynomial has an inverse, one would expect to obtain the plots of these inverses by a reflection on the line $y=x$.

My question is the following: Is there a way to obtain a closed formula for the inverse polynomial directly from its plot?

Comment: Solving the equation $p(x)=y$ for $y=0$ is just a trivial subset of solving it in general. Thus if you cannot find an algebraic formula for $x$ in terms of the coefficients of $p(x),$ then much more would you be pressed to find a formula for $x$ in the equation  $p(x)-y=0$ in terms of the coefficients and $y.$

Comment: As you note, the plot of the inverse is obtained by a simple reflection along the line $y=x$. So obtaining a closed formula for the inverse polynomial from its plot is just as easy or hard as obtaining a closed formula for the polynomial itself from its plot. Of course whether you can give a closed form of a function from its plot depends very much on what data you mean by 'its plot' precisely.